# Display text according to the access to a field

Tags: 7, entities, users, files

With [field permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions), I restrict the access of a field to certain users.

I would like to display some text to inform the user that he has no access to the field.

I tried it in node.tpl.php :

```
<?php if (!field_access('view', field_info_field('field_name'),'node', $node)): ?>
    <p><?php print t('my text.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It works, but I do not know how to restrict according to the type of content.

How can it be done? 
Also, is it the good method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [drupal_set_message](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) in [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) to display the text as a message to the users.

```
function MODULE_NAME_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'your_node_type') {
    if (!field_access('view', field_info_field('field_name'),'node', $node)) {
      drupal_set_message(t('Your text.'), 'warning');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh. I thought of the drupal message, but I prefer one <p>. You know how can it be done? I had also thought of using a field to show the message, but my tries did not work.

Comment: I think you can follow the normal way of adding markup in t(). Something like t('!para_start your text !para_end', array('!para_start' => '<p>', '!para_end' => '</p>'));, but am not so sure if it is the right way. Just give it try

Comment: i try the first code with drupal message and it does'nt work.

Comment: Did you clear the cache? replace MODULE_NAME with your module name. Try to put print_r to check if the condition passes.

Comment: I have clear the cache, but it does not work. I tried `print_r()`, but there also, nothing displays. Would not you rather use `hook_node_view_alter()`? For information, I put this function in my template.php, but I do not think the problem comes from there.

Comment: I think the problem comes from there only :P, you should put the hook in your module and not the theme's template.php. AFAIK you can use hooks in template.php that are only meant for themes. If at all you wanna check if the hook is called in template.php just put `print_r` and `exit` without any conditions. If you don't have custom modules and want to implement from theme only, then you can go for`'template_preprocess_node`. Refer https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7